# Liferay 7.2 Time Zone settings

Tags: time, liferay-7

I have Liferay 7.2

I use this taglib to print current time in my theme:

```
<@liferay.date format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

I want to change the timezone settings from:

Control Panel → Configuration -> Instance Settings -> Localization -> TImeZone

In front-end i always get the same time with any option.

How can i change the locale time?